# Output in txt format in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasperserver

I'm using JasperReports Server 6.4.2. And in "Output Options" tab of "New Schedule" windows I have such list of output formats:

[image]

And I would like to add here .txt format. I uncommented the following line in *\JasperReports Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\flows\viewReportBeans.xml* file:

```
<!--
<entry key="txt" value-ref="txtExporterConfiguration"/>
 -->
```

and uncommented the lines:

```
<!-- 
        <bean class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.dto.ByteEnum">
            <property name="code">
                <util:constant static-field="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.domain.ReportJob.OUTPUT_FORMAT_TXT"/>
            </property>
            <property name="labelMessage">
                <value>report.output.txt.label</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
-->
```

in *\JasperReports Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\flows\reportJobBeans.xml* file, but these actions didn't make any visual effect, the "Text only" format didn't appear on the "Formats" form. How to add this format on the form?

I found also the similar [question](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/5481) on the official jasper site, but, unfortunately, without answer... It seems the matter is in 6.x version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found [instruction](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-add-txt-exporter-scheduler-output-options-tibco-jasperreports-server-v601-and-newer) how to do this. The steps that I lacked: editing *\JasperReports Server\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\scripts\scheduler\view\editor\outputTabView.js* file and disabling "javascript.optimize" property in WEB-INF\js.config.properties file. After these actions "TXT" checkbox eventually appeared on the form:

[image]

Comment: Please note, it's not recommended to disable JavaScript optimization as it will increase the loading times in browsers. The article you link references the documentation on how to re-run the optimization.

Comment: @Kamal, yes, you are right, thank you for the comment!